# Multitexturing depending on given variables?

Tags: xna, 3d, textures, rendering, hlsl

I'm having trouble with rendering multiple textures.
Using XNA gamestudio: working with 3D meshes and texturing.
Effect.fx HLSL

I do have a map/level that loads from a heightmap. - This works

I have created an effect.fx file that renders the textures. - This works

Multitexturing shader works to a degree where I hardly can alter the function.

So I can fade from different textures if I pass a height value, would have worked fine if the world was meant to be solid/static, but that's not the case here.

I want to hold certain variables to the vertex/faces and alter them in realtime while the vertexshader and the other drawing components renders it correctly as the variables is being altered.

If I wanted to paint a vertex/face red on a Grass-textured plane then this mentioned vertex/face would then be red.

I'm having a hard time finding the problem.
Wasn't able to make a 2 dimensional for loop within the Pass technique loop
"that just made too much thinking and almost crashed the application"

Have looked trough the source codes for a few example app with no success.

I even bought a book on the subject, but all I've got so far is how to render different textures when the vertex/faces reaches a certain height value on the Y axis.

Comment: This type of terrain painting is usually achieved with vertex colours or [Splat Maps](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texture_splatting) — are either of those applicable to your case?

Answer (score -1):

I found that rendering dynamic
Entity-textures in XNA such as cubes or "planes" needs alot of HLSL knowledge, how to throw in shaders and more.

I scrapped my XNA project and started with Java OpenGL "LWJGL".
ThinMatrix had a good tutorial series with a quick runtrough of the glsl shader system.

with "dynamic" I meant rendering and changing the entity-texture in realtime.